# Github - Copying two repos with one SSH key

Tags: git, bash, github

I want to pull two private github repos via bash script to my server. I used to do just one and this worked fine. This is the process that worked for me:

- Generate SSH on server
- Add to github repo's ssh list
- Compelte the git pull request

Now I am trying to do this:

- Generate SSH
- Add key to first github repo's ssh list
- Add key to second github repo's ssh list
- Compelte the first repo git pull request
- Compelte the second repo git pull request

However, when I try to add the same key to the second repo I want to copy, github says it is already in use. How am I supposed to do this? Should I be generating two seperate SSH's keys on the server and use one for one github repo and one for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH keys on github are user-specific and **not** repo-specific.
Did you try to simply git pull from second repo after pulling from the first?

Comment: I get this error when I run it without generating a second SSH key, even though I know the repo address is correct as is the password: 
ERROR: Repository not found.                                                                        
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Where do you set your SSH-keys? My URL for this is: https://github.com/settings/ssh. I don't have private repos, but there you should set access rights based on accounts and not SSH-keys, too. Another person, with access to your repo is called a Collaborator on github. [Github Help for "Repository not found" error.](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found)